# Visual Studio 2019 Developer PowerShell v16.9.4 not working

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2019

I have an issue or question with regards to **Visual Studio 2019 Developer PowerShell v16.9.4**.

I have Visual Studio Professional 2019, Version 16.9.4.

When I right click on my Solution and select *Open in Terminal* then Visual Studio 2019 Developer **PowerShell** v16.9.4 opens... but it doesn't allow me to put/execute any command son it.
My impression is that it's not fully loaded or something...

By contrast if I open Visual Studio 2019 Developer **Command Prompt** as you can see from the image bellow:[image] v16.9.4 I'm able to execute commands on it.

And this is what happens with the **PowerShell**
[image]

*Note*:  I know there's the settings options but I haven't modified anything yet there.

Am I missing somthing or someone else could point me in the right direction to make it work?

Comment: Does anything happen if you press [Enter] in the seemingly hung PowerShell prompt?

Comment: No, unfortunately nothing happens . Not even with [Enter] or any other key or not even with the combination for instance CTRL+C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved or found a workaround.
In my initial post, I did mention that I knew that there was a **settings option** but I haven't done anything there ... yet.

Finally, I solved going in that direction.
So, just in case someone else faces the same or similar situation.

My ***built-in*** **Developer PowerShell** (inside Visual studio) is configured as follows:

```
shell location: C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
Arguments: -NoExit -Command "& { Import-Module $env:VSAPPIDDIR\..\Tools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevShell.dll}; Enter-VsDevShell -SkipAutomaticLocation -SetDefaultWindowTitle -InstallPath $env:VSAPPIDDIR\..\..\
```

So, I created a new Developer PowerShell settings called: "Sebas PowerShell" (quite original ) and with the following settings (fewer arguments):

```
shell location: same location pointing to powershell.exe
Arguments: -NoExit
```

Like this, it works perfectly fine.
So, I guess it might be related to DevShell.dll or to the other arguments.
In any case, now I can use the Developer PowerShell inside Visual Studio

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a bit late, but I have found that if you have a project selected in Solution Explorer and then choose Open In Terminal, it works fine. If you have any other node selected, the Powershell window opens, but you can't type anything.

No need to create new settings.

Makes sense I suppose, as the point of the terminal is to run commands related to a specific project.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer even if  it isa little bit late ;)
I don't have VS 2019 any longer but in 2022 for instance if I do what you say: "have any other node selected".  Then, the Developer PowerShell opens in the selected StartUp project.